# change variable value with a dropdown menu

Tags: php, javascript

I have created a pagination system, that shows 15 colums from a database.
now I want to add a drop down menu with other values, so I can change the pagination variable to 50 or 100.

I have done a javascript, but it wont work as I want to ;)  It only read the last value I give the script, And nothing happends when I change the dropdown.

Some of the script

```
$per_page = 15; // Shows how many colums it shows per page
```

My javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function addit(){ 
    if(document.getElementById("add").value=="<?php $per_page = 15; ?>") 
    { 
        document.getElementById("amount").value="10" 
    } 
    if(document.getElementById("add")."<?php $per_page = 25; ?>") 
    { 
        document.getElementById("amount").value="25" 
    } 
    if(document.getElementById("add").value=="<?php $per_page = 50; ?>") 
    { 
        document.getElementById("amount").value="50" 
    } 
} 
</script>
```

And the form

```
<form action=" " method="get"> 
<select style="width: 60px; font-size: 17px;" name="add" id="add" onChange="addit()">
<option value="X"> views</option> 
<option value="10">10</option> 
<option value="25">25</option> 
<option value="50">50</option> 
</select> 
</td> 
</tr> 

</tbody> 
</table> 
</form>
```

Any tips ?

thanks

Comment: First off `if(document.getElementById("add")."<?php $per_page = 25; ?>")` is not valid code

Comment: Secondly `if(document.getElementById("add").value=="<?php $per_page = 15; ?>")` doesn't make a lot of sense to me....

Comment: Thirdly, store the return of `getElementById` instead of calling it so often, you can even store the `.value` part. Fourthly, all of those conditionals are running even if a previous one has been found to be true, use `else if` or if that's all the function does just `return` after a find.

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand the different points where PHP Javascript are executed. PHP builds a HTML page *on the server* and then sends it to the browser, where any Javascript is executed.

Let's look at one line of your code:

```
if(document.getElementById("add").value=="<?php $per_page = 15; ?>")
```

The server will execute the PHP part. But `$per_page = 15` does not output anything to the HTML result. So if you look at the result in the Browser (use "View Source"), it will look like this:

```
if(document.getElementById("add").value=="")
```

All three `if` statements in you Javascript will look like this, *all the same*.

Rethink your code from here. If the amount of elements per page is determined in the PHP part, you need to reload the page, somehow passing this parameter to the server, to tell it how many elements to put into the page.

Answer (score 0):

PHP has already finished processing at the moment the page is sent to the browser, so you php assignments in your javascript will not do anything except assign a number before the page is sent to the browser.

What you need to do is:

- post the value of the changed javascript variable and your pagination variables back to the server / **submit the form**
- regenerate the page using the new value
- optionally use ajax to refresh only part of your page instead of doing a complete reload.

Comment: Echo statements in javascript? I see none.

Comment: Umm, yes it does, it changes a lot. He is setting the value of an element to a new value (if the conditionals made sense) and he says he created the pagination system so maybe that is all it needs to work properly. _(I have my doubts about that last part)_

Comment: @TheZ No it doesn't, no php code is run when the javascript function is called as php is already processed server side and javascript client-side. If you look at the source code of the page / the javascript, you will see nothing there.

Comment: Well the pagination part is working like a charm, But its changing the value part that bothering me. But I will try with the else if and store the value part.

Comment: @Felipe Otarola You need to replace your complete `addit` function with a simple form submit (including the pagination variables), optionally using ajax.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest your JS function does load the (same?) page with a `GET` parameter attached, to pass the `items per page` value. Maybe something like:

```js
function addit(){
    var itemsPerPage = document.getElementById("add").value;
    location.href = 'url of your page' + '?ipp=' + itemsPerPage;
}
```

Then in your `php` part, catch the `$_GET['ipp']` and use it to render your page according to the viewer's wish.

And then you can get rid of the `<form>`.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is any need for Javascript here. You can just try:

Form:

```
<form action="process.php" method="get"> 
   <select style="width: 60px; font-size: 17px;" name="add">
        <option value="X" disabled>Views</option>
        <option value="10">10</option> 
        <option value="25">25</option> 
        <option value="50">50</option> 
    </select> 
</form>
```

`Process.php` could be:

```
$per_page = $_GET['add'];

//Code to display $per_page number of items..
```

For sure the PHP variable assigning on Client-side is not going to work ever. Because PHP can not be executed on Client-side. It has already finished executing and outputted the HTML at this point. Or you could use some Javascript `Get` query building & redirect.